# Trying to copy/mount file to AWX kubernetes pod but getting error

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-helm, ansible-awx

I'm attempting to add a file to the /etc/ directory on an AWX task/web container in kubernetes. I'm fairly new to helm and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The only thing I've added to my helm chart is krb5 key in configmap and an additional volume and volume mount to both task and web container. The krb5.conf file is in charts/mychart/files/

ConfigMap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "awx.fullname" . }}-application-config
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "awx.name" . }}
    helm.sh/chart: {{ include "awx.chart" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
data:
  krb5: |-
  {{ .Files.Get "krb5.conf"}}
  secret_key: {{ .Values.awx_secret_key }}
  awx_settings: |
    *some stuff*
```

Deployment:

Volumes add to bottom of deployment.yaml

```
volumes:
  - name: {{ include "awx.fullname" . }}-application-config
    configMap:
      name: {{ include "awx.fullname" . }}-application-config
      items:
        - key: awx_settings
          path: settings.py
        - key: secret_key
          path: SECRET_KEY
  - name: {{ include "awx.fullname" . }}-application-config-krb5
    configMap:
      name: {{ include "awx.fullname" . }}-application-config
      items:
        - key: krb5
          path: krb5.conf
```

Volume Mounts add to both task/web container

```
 volumeMounts:
   - mountPath: /etc/tower
     name: {{ include "awx.fullname" . }}-application-config
   - mountPath: /etc
     name: {{ include "awx.fullname" . }}-application-config-krb5
```

I'm trying to mount a file to the containers in a kubernetes pod and am getting the following error:

```
  Warning  Failed     40s                kubelet, aks-prdnode-18232119-1  Error: failed to start container "web": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:424: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/var/lib/docker/containers/d66044fe204abbf9a4d3772370d0f8d4184e339e59ad9a018f046eade03b8418/resolv.conf\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d9fa9705d70bbb864ed526a96f6a2873b2720c41a9f9ef5b4a428902e4cf3c82/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d9fa9705d70bbb864ed526a96f6a2873b2720c41a9f9ef5b4a428902e4cf3c82/merged/etc/resolv.conf\\\" caused \\\"open /var/lib/docker/overlay2/d9fa9705d70bbb864ed526a96f6a2873b2720c41a9f9ef5b4a428902e4cf3c82/merged/etc/resolv.conf: read-only file system\\\"\"": unknown
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`subPath:`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/#volumemount-v1-core) option to "reach into" that `-application-config-krb5` and mount only the one file:

```
- mountPath: /etc/krb5.conf
  name: {{ include "awx.fullname" . }}-application-config-krb5
  subPath: krb5.conf
```

since, as the error correctly points out, you for sure don't want to blow away the `/etc` directory of almost *any* container environment (it'll nuke `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/hosts`, `resolv.conf`, and a bazillion other important files)

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know it wiped everything in the directory that you mount to, however, using krb5.conf as the subpath doesn't work because it's a file not a directory: `\\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type`

Comment: Ah, I miss read. I got it working, your help was much appreciated!

Comment: You can also fix the issue by putting the file in a new directory instead of a existing directory. For example, mountPath: /etc/myNewDirectory. No subPath needed in that case.

Comment: @Almenon You'll want to be cautious, as `/etc/krb5.conf` is not some random path, it's the default for the kerberos system -- that'd be like saying "oh, /etc/passwd bothers, you just move it"

Comment: Good point. I was referring to solving this error in general. I got this error in a different context where I don't have to worry about kerberos.